# Xcode Plugin release on Mac App Store

Tags: xcode, mac-app-store

I have just started developing a plug-in for Xcode 6. I am planning to release that on Mac App Store.

When I tried to search the Mac App Store to check if there are any Xcode Plug-ins available or not, I could not find any.

So now I am wondering whether Apple will approve Xcode plug-ins or not.

Has anyone tried to do something simillar? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that there is no formal support for Xcode plugins, so this information may change and/or become obsolete as Apple makes changes to Xcode. Also, as it is unsupported, you will not be able to submit this plugin to the Mac App Store.

This [quote](http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/creating-an-xcode4-plugin/) is for older version of Xcode, but I think the answer is still the same. You can read more [here](http://nshipster.com/xcode-plugins/).